# How to prevent NULL spinner?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I am populating a spinner from a DB. It works great. Except that if that part of the DB has not been filled out yet and the spinner is empty. That is a problem when someone tries to append to that part of the DB with a blank spinner, you get a `nullpointerexception`. I have tried all kinds of variations of

```
if (spinner == null) {warn the person and finish()}
```

Or

```
if (spinner.equals(""){warn the person blah blah blah}.
```

Any Solution?

Comment: We have no idea how to help without seeing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with the DB, you probably use a `Cursor` object. Can you not check the count of object in the `Cursor` with `c.getCount()`  ?

```
if (c.getCount() == 0) {
    warn the person and finish()
}
```

Comment: And as Falmarri said, it would help if you show us your code.

Comment: I got it! Thanks! I was looking for something in the results of the cursor instead of counting the results. Sometimes its the most obvious things that get by me lol.  Thanks!